# Is it window based or view based app?

Tags: iphone, window, view

I need to make an iphone app like USA Free that's in App Store.
Can anybody, please, tell me what kind of app is this (window or view based) and how it is possible to make horizontal slide effect when changing views?
Thank you!

Comment: What Xcode template an application starts from doesn't really matter, because you'll probably replace most of that initial code anyway.  These are just minimal projects to get you started, not types of applications that limit what you can do later.

Comment: thnx alexy13 and Brad Larson :)

Answer (score 0):

For transitions, take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:

All apps contain one (or more) windows and views. You might want to start with the basic of creating an app. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595

Comment: Could you please download and install this USA FREE app on your iphone and tell me what do you think: Does they use a navigationController to switch views (because slide effect is the same as navController). thnx.

Answer (score 0):

View based just means the project comes with a default class already setup.  You can put anything you want in that class.  Window based is just if you want to create all the classes your self.  Theres not much difference, so it doesn't really matter which you choose as long a you know how to create the horizontal slide effect your going for.